# How to use `respond_to` and `respond_with` for multiple actions?

Tags: templates, ruby-on-rails-3, controller

I have a few views and the controller actions look like this:

```
def active
  @posts = current_user.posts
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html{ render :template => "posts/list" }
    format.js  { render :template => "posts/list.js" }
  end
end
```

I always want to render those templates above for a lot of the actions in the PostsController.

I'm at a loss how to proceed.

I'm looking for something like:

```
class PostsController

  respond_to :html, :js

  def active
      @posts = current_user.posts

      #respond with the appropriate template (posts/list.html.erb or (posts/list.js.erb):
      respond_with(....what goes here...??)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're going about this the wrong way. The first thing you should do is stick to RESTful resources. So get rid of your `active` method on your `Posts` controller. Instead, nest the `Post` resource under your `User`. So do this in your routes

```
resources :users do
    resources :posts
end
```

This will give you routes that look like this `/users/:user_id/posts` and you can access it from your views using `user_posts`

Then create the appropriate views for html, js, etc. You'll find all the info you need [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)

Hopefully this gets you pointed in the right direction.